# how offset can be added to program counter?

Tags: c, architecture

Basically, Program Counter might have unsigned int value:

For example, if PC is `0b11110000(240)`, then we think that it's 240, not the negative value.

However, if we add offset(sign-extended) to above `PC(0b11110000)`, the added value can be negative or positive:

> For example, if we add 0b11111001(-7) to PC 0b11110000(240), the PC should have 233(which means we do add operation between unsigned and signed). However, if offset is positive value, then PC 0b11110000(240)
>   + offset 0b00001111(15) = 255(which means we do add operation between unsigned and signed)

How add operation between unsigned and signed can be done?

Comment: Offset can't be negative. IP is the offset it self into the segment pointed by cs register.

Comment: @TonyTannous
 Do you mean that PC can't be jumped into previous instruction?

Comment: How do you add to the PC? Perhaps you subtract an unsigned 7 to get to 233.

Comment: Are you talking about the program counter register? But then what does it have to do with the `[c]` tag?

Comment: I was making simulator by using c language, and need to control Program Counter value with binary operation. However, there exists a chance to add sign-extended binary offset to binary Program Counter value.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) arithmetic is that it works consistently for both signed and unsigned quantities.  In fact, much of the time, the CPU doesn't know/care whether it's operating on signed or unsigned quantities -- up to a point (and especially for addition and subtraction), it's mostly a matter of interpretation.

You asked about 240 + -7 and 240 + 15.  Let's look at both of those problems in both the signed and unsigned domains:

1. unsigned + signed:

   240 + -7 = 233

   240 + 15 = 255
2. unsigned + unsigned:

   240 + 249 = 233 (489 % 256)

   240 + 15 = 255
3. signed + signed:

   -16 + -7 = -23

   -16 + 15 = -1
4. signed + unsigned:

   -16 + 249 = -23

   -16 + 15 = -1

What's going on here?  Well, 233 unsigned is the same as -23 signed: they're both 11101001 (in 8 bits).  In binary the two problems look like this:

```
11110000 + 11111001 = (1)11101001

11110000 + 00001111 =    11111111
```

The first result overflows: It's really 111101001 (489), but it overflows and we lose the 9th bit, resulting in 11101001 (233).

The rest is all interpretation.  `11110000` is -16 signed, or 240 unsigned.  `11111001` is -17 signed, or 249 unsigned.  `11101001` is -23 signed, or 233 unsigned.  `11101111` is -1 signed, or 255 unsigned.  And `00001111` is always 15.

(All of this assumes two's complement.  Things would be rather different in one's complement, or sign/magnitude.  But two's complement is what your computer uses.)